# How to supply options to Steam in Ubuntu at launch?

Tags: steam

A recent, terrible update to the Steam launcher has removed 'small mode' as a menu option.

Steam forum suggestions have helped me start the Windows version of Steam under wine in small mode by the command `wine start steam://open/minigameslist`

But I can't get this option to work when running the Linux version. How do I supply this option to Steam when starting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu `steam://open/minigameslist` can be used as an argument with `steam` command, i.e.,

```
steam steam://open/minigameslist
```